# Exe file created using pyinstaller shuts immediately when executing

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller

I've tried to create an executable file using pyinstaller (python 3.6) I've tried to to do this on windows 10 using(also python 3.5) py2exe, and freeze(something), but only pyinstaller was "brave" enough to create an exe file.

When I was opening the file.py through command prompt - no problem occured. But when I was trying to execute the file.exe - there is showing up a black window like a command prompt, and suddenly it disappears, while the file.exe is not executing.
While creating an exe.file I had few warnings in command prompt:

```
12914 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\krzys\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\DLLs\tk86t.dll
12986 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\krzys\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\DLLs\tk86t.dll
13141 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\krzys\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
13210 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\krzys\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
13284 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\krzys\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
13357 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\krzys\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
13432 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\krzys\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
13505 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\krzys\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
13576 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\krzys\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
13646 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\krzys\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
13725 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\krzys\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
```

and on and on and on...
but finally in the end I had this info:

```
15204 INFO: checking COLLECT
15204 INFO: Building COLLECT because out00-COLLECT.toc is non existent
15206 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc
21221 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc completed successfully.
```

Here is my code - a little bit long
https://codepaste.net/o53jx9

This is my first time trying to create an exe file

Comment: try to get printScreen of the black cmd window and paste it here.

Comment: I recently used pyinstaller on python 3.6 .I got these warnings too.But it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Might sound simple, but run as administrator? Looks like it might be having permission access errors if CMD is working.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the exe in cmd it will tell you exactly what is causing it to crash.

run your .exe from the command window, and not from double clicking it. Then edit your answer and post the error that is given.

Its more than likely you are missing an file that your .py script needs in order to run, which would cause it to crash